# Add space between columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I join multiple fields and at the same time add space between each field? I have three fields and I joined them but I want to add space between the names and surnames.
I have it that way.

```
 select name+''+motherlastname+''+last name
 from dbo.employee
```

Comment: Please provide some sample input and the expected output.

Comment: umm... what is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always put spaces in there;

```
select [name] + ' ' + [motherlastname] + ' ' + [last name]
from [dbo].[employee]
```

You're currently separating the fields with a zero length field, that's not going to actually do anything to how they display.

Here's a join using that field, I think that's what you're after.

```
SELECT
    e.[name] + ' ' + e.[motherlastname] + ' ' + e.[last name]
    ,t2.[AnyField]
FROM [dbo].[employee] e
INNER JOIN [dbo].[table2] t2
    ON e.[name] + ' ' + e.[motherlastname] + ' ' + e.[last name] = t2.FieldName
```

Comment: @marth a. Yeah, this seems pretty obvious.  Unless we're missing something?

Comment: this won't work... I believe you want `[last name]` or `last, name` or `last + ' ' + name`

Comment: @Hogan you're right, didn't even check that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @RichBenner -- my guess it that was the answer to the real question asked here but the poster never said what the actual problem was.

Comment: @MarthA. -- put `AS new_field_name` after it.  And you don't mean "linking" you mean "selecting"

Comment: @MarthA. I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you have another question I'd post it separately.